# Run Knex migration from node server

Tags: mysql, node.js, migration, knex.js

I want to run these knex commands automatically every time my app is starting :

```
knex migrate:make createUserTable
knex migrate:latest
```

How to do so using my knex object, from my server.js node file, not console command ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [migration API](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations-API)

In your case it should be :

```
knex.migrate.make(createUserTable)
```

(untested)